# How can I see additional details about the lease for an Azure Blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to see any details about a lease that is attached to a container. I can see the lease state and duration on the portal, however I am assuming there is more information about the lease that I can use to identify if there is a VM or something that uses that lease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however I am assuming there is more information about the lease that I
>   can use to identify if there is a VM or something that uses that lease

Unfortunately there's none. Typically lease has 3 properties - lease state, duration and id. While lease status and duration are exposed, lease id is not and is the responsibility of the lease holder to keep a note of that in case there's a need to renew, release or change the lease.

If a blob (that too page blob) is used as a disk for the VM, you would need to go down VM route, fetch it's properties to find out the URLs of the disks. That information is not stored anywhere along with the blob.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now this is a separate question which is slightly related to this, but if the lease was "broken" will the VM (or whatever resource) be able to re-enable that lease? Or will it need to be manually done?

Comment: Interesting question! So the VM (or fabric controller responsible for spinning up the VM) acquires an infinite lease however any other process can simply break the lease (by using `Break Lease` operation). I am not sure if the VM/Fabric controller can detect by itself that the lease on the blob has broken and it needs to reacquire the lease. In my experience, the answer is no.